# Reconstruct signal using InverseFourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

I start from a signal, I do discrete Fourier transform of the signal, and I want to get back this same signal doing a discrete inverse Fourier transform. However, when I do so, I do not obtain the same signal back. What am I missing?

Here I give the code of a simple example:

```
signal[i_] := 
 UnitStep[(i*samplingPeriode) + 0.5] - 
  UnitStep[(i*samplingPeriode) - 0.5]

initialTime = -5;
finalTime = 5;
signalDuration = finalTime - initialTime;

bandwidth = 50;
nyquistRate = 2*bandwidth;
nyquistSamplingPeriode = 1/nyquistRate;

samplingFrequency = 50*nyquistRate;
samplingPeriode = 1/samplingFrequency;
numberOfSamples = signalDuration/samplingPeriode;

yValuesSampledSignal = 
  Table[signal[i], {i, initialTime/samplingPeriode, 
    finalTime/samplingPeriode}];
xValuesSampledSignal = 
  Table[i*samplingPeriode, {i, initialTime/samplingPeriode, 
    finalTime/samplingPeriode}];
sampledSignal = 
  Partition[Riffle[xValuesSampledSignal, yValuesSampledSignal], 2];

yValuesDiscreteFourierTransform = 
  samplingPeriode*
   Chop[Fourier[yValuesSampledSignal, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]];
xValuesDiscreteFourierTransform = 
  Table[i*(1/signalDuration), {i, 0, numberOfSamples}];
discreteFourierTransform = 
  Partition[
   Riffle[xValuesDiscreteFourierTransform, 
    yValuesDiscreteFourierTransform], 2];

absYValuesDiscreteFourierTransform = 
  Abs[samplingPeriode*
    Fourier[yValuesSampledSignal, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]];
absDiscreteFourierTransform = 
  Partition[
   Riffle[xValuesDiscreteFourierTransform, 
    absYValuesDiscreteFourierTransform], 2];

argYValuesDiscreteFourierTransform = 
  Arg[samplingPeriode*
    Fourier[yValuesSampledSignal, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]];
argDiscreteFourierTransform = 
  Partition[
   Riffle[xValuesDiscreteFourierTransform, 
    argYValuesDiscreteFourierTransform], 2];

yValuesRecontructedSignal = 
  InverseFourier[yValuesSampledSignal, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
xValuesRecontructedSignal = xValuesSampledSignal;
reconstructedSignal = 
  Partition[
   Riffle[xValuesRecontructedSignal, yValuesRecontructedSignal], 2];

ListLinePlot[sampledSignal, PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot[Take[absDiscreteFourierTransform, 50], Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot[Take[argDiscreteFourierTransform, 50], Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[Abs[reconstructedSignal], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: As I remember, the reconstructed signal have to be created from Fourier image of initial one: `recsig=InverseFourier@Fourier@sig` but in your sample of code I've seen the `recsig=InverseFourier[sig]` which is wrong.

Comment: This is nicely set up for a first question to the forum, but, as it seems to arise from a small programming error, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rom38 is correct, you did have a typo where you were applying the inverse transform on the original data, not on the transformed data.  Just change that line to read

```
yValuesRecontructedSignal = (1/samplingPeriode) InverseFourier[
    yValuesDiscreteFourierTransform, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
```

Also, I find it easier and more clear to use `Transpose`, as in

```
`Partition[Riffle[ list1, list2], 2] = Transpose @ {list1, list2}`
```

But really, you don't have to keep the data as a 2D list of `{x, y}` values.  You run into trouble when you run your last plotting command, `ListLinePlot[Abs[reconstructedSignal]]` - since it takes the absolute values of both axes (meaning your negative time values are turned into positive time values).

I find it easier to just specify the [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) of the `ListLinePlot`, as in

```
ListLinePlot[yValuesSampledSignal, 
 DataRange -> {initialTime, finalTime}]
ListLinePlot[Chop@InverseFourier@Fourier@yValuesSampledSignal, 
 DataRange -> {initialTime, finalTime}]
```

[image]

where I'm using the shorthand notation, `f[ g[ x] ] = f @ g @ x`

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your replies! It helped a lot! Sorry for the mistake...